Docker `FROM node` throws `401 Unauthorized` from `GET` (but the `GET` works in Firefox)
XY Problem
What would cause a GET to succeed in Firefox/cURL (200 response) but fail from docker (401 Unathorized)?

Full problem:
Downloaded Docker Desktop & started the tutorial "How do I run a container?"
Step 1
(in CMD as Administrator), clone repo:
C:\>cd temp\sandbox

C:\temp\sandbox>git clone https://github.com/docker/welcome-to-docker
Cloning into 'welcome-to-docker'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 125, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (58/58), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (36/36), done.
remote: Total 125 (delta 33), reused 34 (delta 19), pack-reused 67
Receiving objects: 100% (125/125), 319.54 KiB | 2.88 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (55/55), done.

C:\temp\sandbox>cd welcome-to-docker
C:\temp\sandbox\welcome-to-docker>

Step 2
docker build (fails with 401 Unauthorized):
C:\temp\sandbox\welcome-to-docker>docker build -t welcome-to-docker .
[+] Building 0.5s (3/3) FINISHED                                         docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 669B                                               0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18-alpine            0.4s
 => [auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                        0.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18-alpine:
------
Dockerfile:2
--------------------
   1 |     # Start your image with a node base image
   2 | >>> FROM node:18-alpine
   3 |
   4 |     # The /app directory should act as the main application directory
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: node:18-alpine: failed to resolve source metadata for docker.io/library/node:18-alpine: failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: unexpected status from GET request to https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fnode%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io: 401 Unauthorized

View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/default/default/wop04cctid0oqc9du02kvac1b

Ugh. Nice.
Debug
Tested the err-ing GET in Firefox, it returns the sought-after token:

IDK why, try again
Same dice:
C:\_dev\sandbox\welcome-to-docker>docker build -t welcome-to-docker .
[+] Building 0.6s (3/3) FINISHED                                         docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 669B                                               0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18-alpine            0.5s
 => [auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                        0.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18-alpine:
------
Dockerfile:2
--------------------
   1 |     # Start your image with a node base image
   2 | >>> FROM node:18-alpine
   3 |
   4 |     # The /app directory should act as the main application directory
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: node:18-alpine: failed to resolve source metadata for docker.io/library/node:18-alpine: failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: unexpected status from GET request to https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fnode%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io: 401 Unauthorized

View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/default/default/wzcc4nni8yk8xmgxtqf545jh3

C:\_dev\sandbox\welcome-to-docker>

Debug 2
cURL from CMD works:
C:\_dev\sandbox\welcome-to-docker>curl "https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fnode%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io"
{"token":"eyJhbG...","expires_in":300,"issued_at":"2024-06-05T19:30:04.377916924Z"}

C:\_dev\sandbox\welcome-to-docker>

Question:
So why is docker particularly not recognized as an authorized GET requesting entity by the auth.docker.io??

Question: do you have a firewall/proxy? Another solution: try to logout from docker desktop, I have the same problem and I solved logout from the docker desktop and login without using the button see my response on this thread

@Max was onsite at work which has a network firewall + computer had VPN

I had to log out of docker hub on the web for it to work just the way @Max above mentioned.
